# Fixing width on Android Tablet using Kiosk Lockdown

Tags: android, viewport, kiosk-mode

I have been using Windows 10 tablets to run a quiz at a local exhibition using PowerPoint. We have now moved over to  Android tablets and so I have decided to go with HTML, as it seemed more flexible.
 
I have converted PowerPoint presentation into HTML. I did this using an online convertor.
 
Because the tablets need to be locked I am using An app called kiosk browser. https://www.android-kiosk.com/
 
 This works fine and it will open the HTML file fine on booting up.  However, The issue I have is that when the browser opens the HTML file, I would like it to be full width.

I have changed the viewport settings to :
 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
but this doesn't seem to have made any difference when I view the file on a desktop or on the tablet. Is this something else that I could be doing? T
 
here is a setting in kiosk browser is set to “use wide viewport” but that doesn’t seem to make any difference.
 
According the to the tablet the viewport size should be 1102 x 689 and it is running android 12.